# Algorithm to find the maximum non-adjacent sum in n-ary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, dynamic-programming, maximize

Given an n-ary tree of integers, the task is to find the maximum sum of a subsequence with the constraint that no 2 numbers in the sequence should share a common edge in the tree. 
Example:
           1
         /   \
        2     5 
       / \
      3   4
Maximum non adjacent sum = 3 + 4 + 5 = 12
The following is the faulty extension of the algorithm outlined in http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent?

```
def max_sum(node, inc_sum, exc_sum):
    for child in node.children:
        exc_new = max(inc_sum, exc_sum)
        inc_sum = exc_sum + child.val
        exc_sum = exc_new
        inc_sum, exc_sum = max(max_sum(child, inc_sum, exc_sum),
                               max_sum(child, inc_sum, inc_sum - node.val))
    return exc_sum, inc_sum
```

But I wasn't sure if swapping exc_sum and inc_sum while returning is the right way to achieve the result and how do I keep track of the possible sums which can lead to a maximum sum, in this example, the maximum sum in the left subtree is (1+3+4) whereas the sum which leads to the final maximum is (3+4+5), so how should (3+4) be tracked? Should all the intermediary sums stored in a table?

Comment: I guess I don't quite get the example - shall the paths to the nodes labelled with the terms for the sum be disjunct (no shared ancestor but possibly the root) _or_ shall no two such nodes be siblings?

Comment: @maverickz were you satisfied with answer or do you still have doubts ?

Comment: @greybeard: As per the problem description no two nodes which are included in the sum can share an edge i.e can't have a parent-child relationship

Comment: @sasha: The solution is neat! Sorry I couldn't up vote it for lack of reputation. Also can this algorithm be extended to a graph and if so should we consider the max of all sums with each of the nodes as the starting node?

Comment: to a graph you mean a general graph ?

Comment: @maverickz Solution to such problems by dp only works for special graphs ie those having tree structure. If you want to solve it for a general graph which might have cycles then you cannot use this method, as you will not be able to break problems in sub-problems and thus will not be able to solve by dynamic-programming . In that case I even doubt the solution would be polynomial it would be exponential I guess in time . ( in that case you would have to try all possibilities of selection no other way which is very time consuming for large inputs ). Hope I answered your question.

Comment: @sasha: I totally forgot about the loops in graphs! That sums it up all, thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say **dp[u][select]** stores the answer: maximum sub sequence sum with no two nodes having edge such that we consider only the sub-tree rooted at node **u** ( such that **u** is selected or not ). Now you can write a recursive program where state of each recursion is **(u,select)** where **u** means root of the sub graph being considered and **select** means whether or not we select node **u**. So we get the following pseudo code

```
     /* Initialize dp[][] to be -1 for all values (u,select) */
     /* Select is 0 or 1 for false/true respectively        */

     int func(int node , int select )
     {
         if(dp[node][select] != -1)return dp[node][select];
         int ans = 0,i;

         // assuming value of node is same as node number
         if(select)ans=node;

         //edges[i] stores children of node i
         for(i=0;i<edges[node].size();i++)
         {
             if(select)ans=ans+func(edges[node][i],1-select);
             else ans=ans+max(func(edges[node][i],0),func(edges[node][i],1));
         }
         dp[node][select] = ans;
         return ans;
     }

     // from main call, root is root of tree and answer is
     // your final answer
     answer = max(func(root,0),func(root,1));
```

We have used memoization in addition to recursion to reduce time complexity.Its **O(V+E)** in both space and time. You can see here a working version of 
the code **[Code](http://ideone.com/e.js/2GIDTu)**. Click on the fork on top right corner to run on test case 
 
4 1 
1 2 
1 5 
2 3 
2 4 
It gives output 12 as expected. 
The input format is specified in comments in the code along with other clarifications. Its in C++ but there is not significant changes if you want it in python once you understand the code. Do post in comments if you have any doubts regarding the code.

Comment: Shouldn't the test case be  4 1 
1 2 
1 5 
2 3 
2 4

Comment: I have specified the input format and given a link you can run on your testcases also

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that the first two arguments are the number of edges and the root node and thought that they were parent child nodes as well.